# Impression tracking on dynamic content block with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic, content, tracking-extract

I want to add Impression tracking to a dynamic content block that is added with AMPscript.

So the dynamic content block looks like this in our email template:

```ampscript
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Content Units\Abandon Cart\TopBanner")=%% %%[ENDIF]%%
```

How do I add BEGINIMPRESSIONREGION and ENDIMPRESSIONREGION the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the BEGINIMPRESSIONREGION right after your opening IF statement, and then ENDIMPRESSIONREGION right before the ENDIF. This ensures it is only counted if a subscriber meets that certain condition. Example, assuming you may want to mix in some HTML:

```ampscript
%%[ IF x == y THEN ]%%

%%=BeginImpressionRegion("Section 1: X is equal to Y")=%% 

%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Content Units\Abandon Cart\TopBanner")=%%

%%=EndImpressionRegion()=%%

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you for your feedback. I just have one question - the IF/THEN statement is added in the dynamic content block, so when we are adding it to our email template we haven't had the need for a IF/THEN. So how do we then add the BEGINIMPRESSIONREGION?